# kpathsea and path prefixes

Tags: paths, file-lookup

On page 27, the kpathsea manual states:

- [A search path is a colon-separated list of path elements.]
- ...
- To check a particular path element `e`, Kpathsea first sees if a prebuilt database  applies to `e`, i.e., if the database is in a directory
  that is a prefix of `e`. If so, the path specification is matched against the contents of the database.

A few things aren't clear in the last sentence of this description. I'd be much obliged if somebody could point me to a more accurate description or provide an explanation how it works. The following are some questions I have.

1. The path element `e` may have several prefixes. In what order are they searched? For example, if `e` is equal to `/a/b/c`, then `/a` and `/a/b` are both prefixes of `e`. (I suspect the order is given by: longest prefix first ... shortest prefix last.)
2. Is `e` a prefix of itself? (I supect yes.)

The following is a possible solution to Question 1. Could it be that there is an implicit assumption that there may be at most one prefix of any path element that can may an `ls-R` database? If so, should the directory containing the `ls-R` database be in `TEXMFDBS`? It would make sense. For example, `find /usr/local/texlive -name ls-R` gives:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/ls-R
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/ls-R
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/ls-R
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/ls-R
```

and `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFDBS` gives:

```
{!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist}
```

**EDIT (2 March, 2012)** I sent [an email](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2012-March/002388.html) to the `kathsea` mailing list. I got [a reply from Karl Berry](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2012-March/002389.html) suggesting that there should be no more than one `ls-R` database along one path leading from the root to any leaf. Also, the directory containing the ls-R database should be in `TEXMFDBS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The expert suggests](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-k/2012-March/002389.html) that there should be no more than one `ls-R` database along one path leading from the root to any leaf. Also, the directory containing the ls-R database should be in `TEXMFDBS`.